# How to define a different connection pool by deployed application in glassfish

Tags: java, mysql, jakarta-ee, glassfish, jpa-2.0

I am using glassfish 4 and java EE 7. I would need to define a connection pool that is different for each application I will deploy in glassfish.

I have one application (.war file) per client, and each client has its own user/password/schema in my mysql db, so the data is not shared between the clients.
I know how to define a connection pool in glassfish, but then all my applications can only use the same settings (I am using bonecp btw).
I would like to be able to change the user/password/schema for each application deployed. Is it possible to define entirely the connection pool in persistence.xml and not in glassfish, so I could have a different one within my different .war files?
With 10 .war files deployed (10 clients), I would like to have 10 different connection pools (different user/password/schema defined).

Comment: Did you find a solution to this ? I tried using instances, so the same application gets deployed on all instances, but it still shares the jdbc resources. I see there is something called domains and virtual servers also but I haven't quite figured those out yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you create the data source programmatically, then you can inject it to JPA without a need to declare it in your persistence.xml. Here's an example

Define the persistence-xml:

```xml
<persistence-unit name="foo-PU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <!-- the provider: Hibernate, EclipseLink or another -->
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

    <!-- No need to define any connection parameter nor the data source -->

    <!-- class definitions here -->
</persistence-unit>
```

Defining a .properties file to store the configuration for the data source:

```
db.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/foo_db
db.user=user
db.password=s3cr3t
db.bonecp.idleConnectionTestPeriod=60
db.bonecp.idleMaxAge=240
db.bonecp.maxConnections=10
# more properties...
```

Defining a class that will generate the data source

```
public class DataSourceGenerator {
    public static DataSource getDataSource(String properties) {
        Properties conf = new Properties();
        try {
            conf.load(
                DataSourceFactory.class
                .getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(
                    properties));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //handle the error
            //naive handling shown here
            e.printStacktrace();
        }
        BoneCPDataSource dataSource = new BoneCPDataSource();
        //set the properties from the .properties file
        dataSource.setDriverClass(conf.getProperty("db.driver"));
        dataSource.setJdbcUrl(conf.getProperty("db.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(conf.getProperty("db.user"));
        dataSource.setPassword(conf.getProperty("db.password"));
        dataSource.setIdleConnectionTestPeriodInMinutes(
            Long.parseLong(
                conf.getProperty("db.bonecp.idleConnectionTestPeriod")));
        dataSource.setIdleMaxAgeInSeconds(
            Long.parseLong(
                conf.getProperty("db.bonecp.idleMaxAge")));
        dataSource.setMaxConnectionsPerPartition(
            Integer.parseInt(
                conf.getProperty("db.bonecp.maxConnections")));
        //more properties to load...
        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

Create your `EntityManagerFactory` programmatically as well:

```
public class EntityManagerFactoryGenerator {
    public static EntityManagerFactory createEMF() {
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        String dataSourceKey = "";
        //uncomment here depending on your needs...
        //using Hibernate
        //dataSourceKey = org.hibernate.cfg.AvailableSettings.DATASOURCE;
        //using EclipseLink
        //dataSourceKey = org.eclipse.persistence
        //    .config.PersistenceUnitProperties.NON_JTA_DATASOURCE;
        properties.put(
            dataSourceKey,
            DataSourceGenerator.getDataSource("mysql-con.properties"));
        return Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("foo-PU", properties);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1. Go to Glassfish admin console to configure the JDBC connection details.

Inside Resources - JDBC create one pool for each set of connection details, then create a JDBC data source to each created pool.

Step 2. Go to your persistence file of each application and point to the right data source.

Don't specify the provider if you don't need anything special as Glassfish comes with EclipseLink already, which works fine.